# phpStorm SVN Lock Message

Tags: svn, locking, phpstorm

How can I see the Lock-Message (not the log-message!!) for a previous LOCKed file in PHPStorm?

The repository view does not seem to support this?

To clarify this I am talking about svn's LOCK command. Not FileLocking or locked working copy

Comment: Not sure about PHPStorm, but from the command-line you can use [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) to get the information regarding the lock. [More info about locking here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html).

Comment: @SameerSingh: thanks for the info, yes I know that it is possible, but I am searching for a solution in phpStorm(it is for a training and attendees have only phpStorm)